# appending location var has no effects in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its totally strange for me where i have a requirement where i need to redirect to different URL by changing the url....here what i am doing

```
 var newURLString = window.location.pathname +"/"+ data.area;
              window.location.href = newURLString;
               alert(window.location.href);
            location.reload();
```

This code works perfectly but the **STRANGEST** thing is if i remove alert it doesn't works! Loads the current URL.....

NOTE:***alert shows me the correct url and redirects to correct url but removing this loads to current url***

Comment: just remove location.reload(); You dont need it. It just reloads the current page.

Comment: @CemŞengezer cool it working :) y does reload is not required ???

Comment: Yes it is not nequired. window.location.href = newURLString does it already. reload is only to refresh current page

Comment: Without the alert, the reload is just reloading the current page. With the alert, the new page has time to get loaded before you call reload, which loads the new page again

Comment: @Tibrogargan yeh this make sens :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove location.reload(); You dont need it. It just reloads the current page.

```
var newURLString = window.location.pathname +"/"+ data.area;
                  window.location.href = newURLString;
                   alert(window.location.href);
                //location.reload();
```